# How can I use for loop to iterate through vector? I tried to look it up on YouTube and couldn't find the answer

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

I can't figure out how to use for loop to access the vector's elements to find the average. I tried to look for a solution, but I couldn't find anything. The little piece of code that I wrote doesn't seem like the solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   const int VALS_SIZE = 6;
   vector<int> valsVctr(VALS_SIZE);
   unsigned int i;
   int sumVal;
   int avgVal;

   valsVctr.at(0) = 30;
   valsVctr.at(1) = 20;
   valsVctr.at(2) = 20;
   valsVctr.at(3) = 15;
   valsVctr.at(4) = 5;
   valsVctr.at(5) = 10;

   sumVal = 0;
   avgVal = 0;
   /* FIXME: Write for loop to iterate through vector */

   for(int i = 0; i < 7;i++)
   valsVctr[i] = i+1;

   avgVal = sumVal / VALS_SIZE;

   cout << "Avg: " << avgVal << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you're better served not trying to learn C++ from YouTube.  It's a complicated language, and you'll want a good book.

Comment: [Here's a list of books generally accepted as good.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use explicit `for` loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < 7;i++)  //
```

You got an out of bound access error with `i = 6`.

Instead use `for-range` loop instead:

```
for(const auto& x: valsVctr)
{
    sumVal += x;
}
avgVal = sumVal / VALS_SIZE;
```

Also, `sumVal` and `avgVal` would be better of type `float` or `double` instead of `int`.

Comment: Note: The `const auto &` is for future-proofing. Now you can toss in just about any container of anything and not have to change as much code.

Comment: You can eliminate the manual loop altogether by using the standard `std::accumulate()` algorithm instead: `sumVal = std::accumulate(valsVctr.begin(), valsVctr.end(), 0);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes that would eliminate the loop altogether (the loop is what OP asked for).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `for` loop with iterators:

```
std::vector<int>::const_iterator iter;
std::vector<int>::const_iterator end_iter(valsVctr.end());
for (iter = valsVctr.begin(); iter != end_iter; ++iter)
{
    std::cout << *iter << endl;
}
```

This would be more safe than an indexed based `for` loop.

If you want to use an indexed `for` loop, use the `size` method for the limit:

```
const unsigned int limit = valsVctr.size();
for (unsigned i = 0; i < limit; ++i)
{
      valsVctr[i] = i + 1;
}
```

*Note:  the size of the vector was assigned to a temporary variable to prevent the `size()` method from being called in each iteration (although compilers may perform this optimization at higher optimization levels).*

Answer (score 0):

each way below works

1. for(int i = 0; i < 6;i++)
   sumVal += valsVctr[i];
2. for(int k : valsVctr)
   sumVal += k; // c++ 11